# Shortcut to run a single bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

I frequently have things I need to do in a fresh context to keep from messing up my workflow. Usually I open a fresh terminal, do whatever, and then by the end of the day I have a bunch of single-command terminal windows open.

Sometimes I remember to add `&& exit` on the end of my command, but sometimes I don't.

Is there a way to run a single command via a hotkey? Mainly useful for `umount /media/[tab][tab]`, but I could find other uses as well. Autocomplete would definitely be an asset.

Comment: Would aliases work for you?

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm asking. I'm fine to type out the command, I'm just not happy with the terminal window hanging around afterwards, + all the overhead of launching a terminal emulator to type a few characters

Comment: I see. Well if the commands are always the same, one option would be to write small executable scripts for each, place them in a local `bin` directory and add that dir to your `PATH` in the `.profile` - It'll be loaded at login and you could use ALT+F2 -> <script_name>.

Comment: Alt+F2 is what I was looking for. It has tab autocomplete, but unfortunately not the autocomplete utilities of applications (umount has its own implementation). Maybe post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For quickly executing commands, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type your command there.

Be careful as some functionalities like redirecting output into files might not be working as expected.